# Add a Trending Proposals tab to the sidebar like Hottest Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51, stack-exchange

I think that currently there is very little exposure for new site proposals (considering how much traffic sites like Stack Overflow generate). I'm not sure that a large amount of the user base even knows that there is an Area 51 site (even though the hottest questions sidebar does help users discover *some* of the lesser-known sites).

I think that something highlighting Area 51 better (such as the trending proposals sidebar) would help a lot more proposals gain the followers and interest they need to succeed. What do people think about that?

Comment: Graduated sites (excluding Stack Overflow) do have their community promotion ads which are allowed to have Area 51 proposal ads. This also further restricts the community to only seeing ones that members think would be relevant and interesting to the community.

Comment: Any more "hottest" titles and the site may be banned by over-zealous workplace NSFW filters.

Comment: @DeerHunter I was actually thinking about the wording when writing this - I think "Trending Network Questions" etc would probably be better.

Comment: @DeerHunter: Given the general effect of HNQ, maybe that's the best thing those overzealous filters have ever done for anyone.